# Get dynamic tail n of each subgroup

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset looks like this. (I'm looking for a data frame solution)

```
df = ({'id':["a","a","a","a","b","b","b"],
      'tail_num' :[2,2,2,2,1,1,1],
      'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

for the subgroup with id 'a', i want to get the latest 2 records which align with the tail_num column, for 'b' I want to get the tail 1 value. What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

The desired output looks like this (basically get tail n values based on tail_num, and display all columns):

```
df = ({'id':["a","a","b"],
      'tail_num' :[2,2,1],
      'value':[3,4,7]})

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, would you be able to re-word this? Are you trying to display the 'value' elements?

Comment: You named your variable `df` ("dataframe") but it appears to be a plain old dictionary. Are you looking for a dictionary solution or a pandas dataframe solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html?highlight=groupby%20apply#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply) the `id` column and apply a *custom/mapped* [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html?highlight=tail#pandas.DataFrame.tail) :

```
dmap = dict(zip(df["id"], df["tail_num"]))

out = df.groupby("id", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.tail(dmap[g.name]))
```

Or without a dictionnary :

```
out = df.groupby(["id", "tail_num"], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.tail(x.name[1]))
```

Ouptut :

```
print(out)

  id  tail_num  value
2  a         2      3
3  a         2      4
6  b         1      7
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i'm looking for. Does dmap need to be a dictionary?

Comment: I updated my answer to create the dictionnary based on the column `tail_num`.

Comment: Great, just tried and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it was originally unclear in the question that you were looking for a Pandas solution , here is how to do it in plain Python.

In the future, please don't leave answerers guessing at what you need like this.

```
counts = {x: 0 for x in set(df["id"])}
results = {"id": [], "tail_num": [], "value": []}

# Iterate through the list, in reverse order
for i in range(len(df["id"]) - 1, 0, -1):
    counts[df["id"][i]] += 1
    # Skip if we already have tail_num entries for this id.
    # Otherwise add to the output.
    if counts[df["id"][i]] <= df["tail_num"][i]:
        results["id"] += [df["id"][i]]
        results["tail_num"] +=[df["tail_num"][i]]
        results["value"] += [df["value"][i]]

# Reverse again to get back the original order.
results = [list(reversed(results[x])) for x in results.keys()]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'a', 'b'], [2, 2, 1], [3, 4, 7]]
```